# Power Decomposition Power of 3

Tags: python

So I am trying to write a program that produces the decomposition of an integer using powers of three which are: 1, 3, 9, 27, and 81.  Can only use the numbers once in each calculation.

example:

1 = 1

2 = 3 – 1

3 = 3

4 = 3 + 1

5 = 9 – 3 – 1

How can I fix this, and also take into account negative numbers too? It works for most numbers but not for 5 for example, it includes 3 twice.

```
add = True;
ans = ""
nums = [1, 3, 9, 27, 81] #list of powers of 3

check = result
while(check): #loop through the value if it exsists
    distance = abs(check - 1)
    close = 1
    for i in nums:
        temp_distance = abs(check-i)
        if (distance and (distance >= temp_distance)): #check if the distance is greater than the temp distance and not a perfect match
            distance = temp_distance
            close = i
        else: #if its a perfect match then no calculation needed
            break
    if close > check: 
        add = not add
    check = distance
    if check:
        ans += str(close)
        if add:
            ans += ' + '
        else:
            ans += ' - '
    else:
        ans += str(close)
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach is converting the number into the ternary base system. For example:

```
32(10 = 1012(3 = 27 + 3 + 2*1
```

Here `(b` represents that the number is in base `b`. According to your algorithm, numbers should be used only once, so you have to work like this:

1) Create a function that converts an integer into a list of powers of three.

```
def powerthree(input):
  if input<0: return powerthree(abs(input))
  powthree = []
  while input > 0:
    powerthree.append(input % 3)
    input /= 3
  powethree.reverse() #Reverse to show factors decreasing to 1
  return powethree
```

2) Add a dummy `0` to the beginning of the list:

```
pw3 = [0] + powerthree(input)
```

3) Scan the list from right to left. If an element is `2`, set to `-1` and add `1` to the previous element of the list, until position 1.

```
def accomodate(pw3list):
  for i in xrange(-1, -len(pw3list), -1): #Run from right to left, rememember that Python allows negative indices!
    if pw3list[i] == 2:
      pw3list[i] = -1
      pw3list[i-1]+=1
  return pw3list
```

4) The values in the accomodated list indicates whether you should add, substract or skip the power of three. Write down the result:

```
def printresult(orignumber, pw3list):
  print "%d = " % orignumber,
  for i in xrange(len(pw3list)):
    pow3 = 3 ** (len(pw3list) - i - 1)
    print "%d" % (pow3 * pw3list[i])
```

Which should print with the example of `32`:

```
32 = 27 + 9 - 3 - 1
```

Hope I'd helped you! And as I usually say, *English is not my mother tongue, so mistakes can be made in my post. Corrections will always be welcome*.